# How to set/change background image of EditText after a digit is input in the EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a set of four editText, for inputting a code from User. After entering first code(which is a digit only) cursor should move to next EditText and the background image of prev EditText should be set with a given image.

I am able to achieve this only when I hit enter button, after entering input. I want it to happen automatically when a digit is entered.

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

    //call for change of image
    v.changeBckgndImage(v);
```

}

Comment: Add TextChangedListener to editttext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText`. So that you can track the input digits by initialising with [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
     // If you want to do anything before text get changed
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     // On Text Change 
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // After Text Changed 
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried using TextWatcher to my editText s. But was not able to figure out the specific view on which I want to take a particular action. But I am able to do that now by :
if (s == first.getEditableText()) 
first.setBackgroundResource(image);

Comment: Thanks for hinting me to try TextWatcher again. I was carried away to use EditActionListener. :)

Comment: No Problems. Happy Coding. Glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a TextChangedWatcher to the edit text using addTextChangedListener, and perform this in afterTextChanged